# My app is "speaking" before the activity has finished setting up, how to fix? (I'm already using onResume())

Tags: android, android-activity, text-to-speech

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
        tts.speak(voiceD, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);


    }

}
```

/* onItin() is already implemented, in fact it works when
 the activity is already set up and I click a button to call
 it, but I want to transition to an Activity after adding in the desired
 voice message via putExtra, and have it speak immediately after the new activity has loaded. Additionally, I've tried debugging but the screen
still wont be displayed after the super.onResume() is called.*/

Comment: I guess I should clarify more. It may not even be able to have the chance to speak since the activity isn't fully loaded yet. I cant tell, since its not speaking at all! But the debugger goes into the if statement so I imagine its executing the code .speak() for the TextToSpeech object namely tts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924296/how-to-use-onwindowfocuschanged-method   this made certain that the activity layout was ready and loaded, onWindowFocusedChanged() with the super overrided

Comment: how are you initializing your tts ? and where are you doing it

Comment: I declared the tts before the onCreate() and initialized it inside the onCreate(). On the Android Developer page they even say that onResume() may not be enough to tell if the screen is fully loaded, which is what I assumed I wanted. They talk about the onWindowFocusedChanged() which I used and it worked for the tablet but not my phone. I introduced a handler in the method, inserted the code, and it finally worked for the phone.