# When to check the clipboard content in Android API 29 when app gets focus?

Tags: android, clipboard

One of the privacy-related changes in API 29 is that an app does not have access to the clipboard unless it is "in focus".

I am trying to fix my app that has a Paste button in the main window (not in a menu), so I need to check if the clipboard has suitable data when the user launches or switches to the app (in order to decide if the Paste button should be enabled). I hoped that when the app is in *OnResume*, is it already allowed to access the clipboard, but it appears that in this state the *getPrimaryClip* still returns *null* even though the clipboard contains a primary clip.

Any suggestion as to which event I should wait for to be sure that my app is already allowed to access the clipboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer at [How to use onWindowFocusChanged() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924296/how-to-use-onwindowfocuschanged-method).

The trick is to check the clipboard within OnWindowFocusChanged when hasFocus boolean parameter is true.